# Creation of test network using ganache

Tags: go-ethereum, blockchain, ganache

Can we reuse the values stored in the ganache test network which is running in the local machine, even if the terminal which is running ganache test network is closed or what are the possible ways to make the ganache network up & running all the time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best way is to use docker.

```
$ docker run -d -p 8545:8545 -v /path/to/local/chain/db:/db trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest --db /db --host 0.0.0.0
```

- `-d` run as a daemon (will stay "up & running all the time")
- `-p 8545:8545` expose the jsonrpc port 8545
- `-v /path/to/local/chain/db:/db` map a local volume `/path/to/local/chain/db` to `/db` in the container so the container will write the chain data on the host.
- `--db /db` Tell Ganache to read/write the chain data into `/db` (mapped into `/path/to/local/chain/db`)
- `--host 0.0.0.0` expose the jsonrpc server outside the container

---

How to stop the daemon container

i. Find the container ID:

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
8e93fb9242e0        trufflesuite/ganache-cli:latest   "node ./build/cli.no…"   19 seconds ago      Up 18 seconds       0.0.0.0:8545->8545/tcp   zealous_davinci
```

ii. Stop the container by passing the container ID

```
$ docker stop 8e93fb9242e0
8e93fb9242e0
```